# Replace array's integer with another integer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array

```
array=[10000,415455,10000,4529856,25632,10000,45556,58456,25654]
```

I want to replace all `10000` with `00000`

How can I do this please?

Comment: What do you mean by `00000`? Zero will be `0`. Do you mean the string `"00000"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to edit in place you need map!

```
array=[10000,415455,10000,4529856,25632,10000,45556,58456,25654]
array.map! {|item| item == 10000 ? 0 : item}
```

When you display just make sure you use some formatting that always displays 5 characters with leading 0's

I believe Ruby does that with

```
array.each {|item|
  puts sprintf "%05d", item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array=[10000,415455,10000,4529856,25632,10000,45556,58456,25654]
array.map {|a| a == 10000 ? '00000' : a}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array=[10000,415455,10000,4529856,25632,10000,45556,58456,25654]
array.map{|i| i == 10000 ? 0000 : i}
# => [0, 415455, 0, 4529856, 25632, 0, 45556, 58456, 25654]
```

Disclaimer: `0000` will be mapped as `0` only.